# unable to use .toList with Data from MongoDB using flutter

Tags: mongodb, flutter

Sorry if it's a stupid question I am beginner in Flutter and MongoDB Here is my code to return collection data btw this is the only time I use Mongo_Dart all other operations done using JS on heroku

```
 class Azkar {
  getAzkar() async {
    var db = await Db.create(
        'mongodb+srv://Adham:<password>@cluster0.nm0lg.mongodb.net/<db>retryWrites=true&w=majority');
    await db.open();
    print('Connected to database');
    DbCollection coll = db.collection('zekrs');

    return await coll.find().toList();
  }
}
```

It is working and I am able to print returned data from another class it is List<Map<String, dynamic>> I want to know how should I use it to generate ListTile with all data.

Comment: would be better if you return in json

Comment: You can't return in json it's either string or list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is not worth it. I solved this issue by moving out this part of code on the backend side (NodeJS) in the cloud and just getting what I need with an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning data in `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, create a class for your data. Suppose your data gives us a list of users. Then

```
class User {
  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
}
```

This would be your `Azkar` class

```
class Azkar {
  getAzkar() async {
    final db = await Db.create(
        'mongodb+srv://Adham:<password>@cluster0.nm0lg.mongodb.net/<db>retryWrites=true&w=majority');
    await db.open();
    print('Connected to database');
    final coll = db.collection('zekrs');

    final zekrsList = await coll.find().toList();
    List<User> users = [];
    for (var item in zekrsList) {
        final user = User(
            id: item['id'],
            name: item['name'],
        );
        users.add(user);
    }
    return users;
  }
}
```

You should do something like this.

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: getAzkar(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text("Name = ${snapshot.data[index].name}"),
                            Text("Id = ${snapshot.data[index].id}"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
```

Comment: await coll.find().toList(); what should I change it for then, thank you so much for the effort

Comment: yeah, for that....
final list = await coll.find().toList();
And use list further wherever I used col1 in the answer.

Pls accept my answer and give an upvote if my answer worked

Comment: for (var v in list) {
        User user = User(
            id: v.id, // error  //
            name: v.name) // error
  The getter 'id' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'id', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'id'.

Comment: The way to access the Map properties is _e.g._ `v['id']` rather than `v.id`

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still have this issue,

I solved it by setting this:

```
final zekrsList = await coll.find().toList();
```

to

```
final zekrsList = await coll.find(where.sortBy('_id')).toList();
```